# Pandas DataFrame values to column names and column names to values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following **x** dataframe:

```
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
1      1
2         1     2
3   1     2        3     4
4   1     3     2     4   
5   2     4     1     3
6      1        2     4  3

x.to_dict()

{'a': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '1', 4: '1', 5: '2', 6: ''},
 'b': {1: '1', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '1'},
 'c': {1: '', 2: '1', 3: '2', 4: '3', 5: '4', 6: ''},
 'd': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: ''},
 'e': {1: '', 2: '2', 3: '', 4: '2', 5: '1', 6: '2'},
 'f': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '3', 4: '', 5: '', 6: ''},
 'g': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '4', 5: '3', 6: '4'},
 'h': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '4', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '3'}}
```

I want to produce this result (column values to column names and column names to column values, keeping the rows information):

```
    1   2   3   4
1   b
2   c   e
3   a   c   f   h
4   a   e   c   g
5   e   a   g   c
6   b   e   h   g
```

Please, note that each row in **x** cannot have repeated values

Comment: Your dataframe is hard to replicate. Can you do `print(x.to_dict())` and paste it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach:

```
d = {'a': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '1', 4: '1', 5: '2', 6: ''},
 'b': {1: '1', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '1'},
 'c': {1: '', 2: '1', 3: '2', 4: '3', 5: '4', 6: ''},
 'd': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: ''},
 'e': {1: '', 2: '2', 3: '', 4: '2', 5: '1', 6: '2'},
 'f': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '3', 4: '', 5: '', 6: ''},
 'g': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '4', 5: '3', 6: '4'},
 'h': {1: '', 2: '', 3: '4', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '3'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars = 'index').query('value!=""')

pd.crosstab(df['index'], df.value, df.variable, aggfunc = 'max')
```

result:

```
value  1    2    3    4
index                  
1      b  NaN  NaN  NaN
2      c    e  NaN  NaN
3      a    c    f    h
4      a    e    c    g
5      e    a    g    c
6      b    e    h    g
```